# How to run Flutter app in iOS simulator without yellow tape box

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, hybrid-mobile-app

When run a Flutter app in iOS simulator, it shows a yellow tape box when there is a layout overflow. Is there any way to disable this behavior? (Because I need to take screenshots for App Store.) I tried to run Flutter in simulator with `--release` but the simulator doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in release mode but then the RenderFlex is still there and simply not shown.

```
flutter run --release
```

[Flutter Buildmodes](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes)

Comment: As described in the question, I tried that but iOS simulator doesn't accept to run release mode.

Comment: iOs emulator doesnt support -release mode. You whether have to connect a real device to your machine. 

Another aproach if you don't have one:

https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview

Comment: This library is so cool! I'll take a look. Thanks!